# How to get object from right click event in wxribbon bar in wxpython?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I am building a GUI and I am using wxribbon for wxpython. I want my user to click on any tab on ribbon bar and rename it. The problem is that I am not able to get the object(tab in this case) from right click on ribbon bar. I am using the following code but it is not working. I am not able to get the page which is right clicked, what I get is the page that is currently active. Any help would be great. Thanks!. The sample code is as follows :

```
self.Bind(RB.EVT_RIBBONBAR_TAB_RIGHT_DOWN, self.RightClickRibbonTabs, id = wx.ID_ANY )

def RightClickRibbonTabs(self,event):
    index, tab = self._ribbon.HitTestTabs(wx.GetMousePosition())
    page = self._ribbon._pages[index].page
    pos = wx.GetMousePosition()
    x, y = pos.x, pos.y
    self.popupmenu = wx.Menu()
    RenameTab = self.popupmenu.Append(-1, "Rename Tab")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, lambda event : self.RenameTab(event, x, y, page), RenameTab)
    pos = wx.GetMousePosition()
    x, y = pos.x, pos.y
    pos = self.ScreenToClient(pos)
    self.PopupMenu(self.popupmenu, pos)

def RenameTab(self, event, x, y, page):
    text = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "Rename Tab :", "Rename Tab", page.GetLabel())
    text.CenterOnParent()
    answer = text.ShowModal()
    text.Destroy()
    if answer == wx.ID_OK:
        newname = text.GetValue()
        page.SetLabel(newname)
        self._ribbon.Realize()
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Please do not put [Solved] in the title. Accepted answer is enough of indicator that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- wx.GetMousePosition() get the positon on the main screen.
- HitTestTabs() should use the position on the ribbon bar.

Here is the solution:

```
def RightClickRibbonTabs(self,event):
    pos = self.ScreenToClient(wx.GetMousePosition())
    index, tab = self._ribbon.HitTestTabs(pos)
    page = self._ribbon._pages[index].page
    pos = wx.GetMousePosition()
    x, y = pos.x, pos.y
    self.popupmenu = wx.Menu()
    RenameTab = self.popupmenu.Append(-1, "Rename Tab")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, lambda event : self.RenameTab(event, x, y, page), RenameTab)
    pos = wx.GetMousePosition()
    x, y = pos.x, pos.y
    pos = self.ScreenToClient(pos)
    self.PopupMenu(self.popupmenu, pos)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! It works perfectly fine. That was great... I understood where I was wrong. Thanks once again....